# An exercise on combinatory logic

Tags: logic, computer-science, combinatory-logic

Can somebody help me with the following exercise?

(1) Find a combinator $X$ such that $Xy = X$; (2) Find a combinator in normal form with the same property. Rules for reduction are

- $Ix > x$
- $Kxy > x$
- $Sxyz > xz(yz)$
- $x > x$
- if $x > x'$ then $Zx > Zx'$
- if $x > x'$ then $xZ > x'Z$
- if $x > y$ and $y > z$ then $x > z$

Equality is the relation generated by reduction and inverse reduction, namely by the previous rules with $=$ in place of $>$ plus

- if $x = y$ then $y = x$.

Abstraction is defined as follows

- $[x]x$ identical with $I$
- $[x]M$ identical with $KM$ if $x$ does not occur in $M$
- $[x]Ux$ identical with $U$ if $x$ does not occur in $U$
- $[x]UV$ identical with $S([x]U)([x]V)$ if the previous cases cannot be applied.

Now, (1) has the simple solution $K(FK)$ where $F$ is a fixed-point combinator. But such a solution does not work for (2) since, if for example one takes $F$ as the Curry fixed-point combinator, $F$ stands for $SWW$ for a certain W and so $K(FK)$ stands for $K(SWWK)$, which is not normal. I can't see how to solve (2).

The author suggests to use a modified version of abstraction, where the second clause is restricted to $M$ atomic, and the third clause is either restricted to $U$ atomic or dropped out.

Any idea?

Comment: I updated my answer with a derivation of the shorter solution $X=S(K(SII)) (K(S(K(S(K(SII))))K))$.

Comment: Thanks very much...anyway, you have worked it out with no reference to the property of the modified definition of abstraction, the one only yielding normal forms. I know, I know...who cares, the important is it does what one looks for!

But, sincerely, I don't think the author required such a complex solution for an exercise occurring at the very beginning of an introductory book! So, as I said elsewhere, I think he maybe meant: find a normal form combinator $X^*$ such that $X^*y = X$, where $X$ is the combinator previously found. (see my last comment below my wrong answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, it was not as straightforward as I had expected, but here is a way through. Suppose $W$ is some term in normal form and we want to find a normal form $X$ such that $Xy=(WX)y$. (For this particular exercise we can take $W=K$, of course).

As long as we're not caring about normal forms, this is fairly easy. Remembering the Y-combinator we can use
$$ X \approx (\lambda f.(\lambda x.f(x x))(\lambda x.f(x x))) W $$
To rewrite that into combinator form, let's assume for simplicity that we have a combinator $D$ with reduction rule
$$ D a \to a a $$
Then, simplifying a bit, we get
$$ \begin{align}X &\equiv ([x] W(D(x)) ([x] W(D(x))
\\ &= D([x] W(D(x))
\\ &\equiv D(S(KW)D) 
\end{align}$$
This works excellently:
$$ \begin{align}Xy \equiv D(S(KW)D)y &\to \big(S(KW)D\,(S(KW)D)\big) y
\\ &\to (KW(S(KW)D))(D(S(KW)D)) y 
\\ &\equiv (KW(S(KW)D)) X y
\\ &\to W X y
\end{align} $$
The only trouble is that $D (S(KW)D)$ is not a normal form. But notice that the only place in the above reduction where we *use* the $D$ reduction is the very first reduction, when $D(S(KW)D)$ does not stand alone but is followed by a $y$! So if we change our reduction rule for $D$ to
$$ D a b \to (aa)b $$
the reduction sequence above *still* goes through, and now $D(S(KW)D)$ *is* a normal form!

Unfortunately we can't just add new combinators willy-nilly. so we have to express $D$ using existing combinators. This means that we can't quite get $D M$ to be a normal form itself, but as long as we can make sure that $D M$ *has* a normal form whenever $M$ has, that will be good enough for us.

First, things will be slightly simpler if we let $D_0 \equiv [a]aa \equiv SII $. Then we take a deep breath, write things down with abstractions, and crank the combinatorfying handle:
$$ \begin{align} D &\equiv [a][b] D_0 a b
\\ &\equiv [a] S ([b] D_0 a) ([b] b)
\\ &\equiv [a] S(S(K D_0)(K a)) I
\\ &\equiv S(S(KS)(S(S(KS)(K(K D_0))(K K)))(KI)
\end{align} $$

The important part here is to resist the temptation to write $K(D_0 a)$ instead of $S(K D_0)(K a)$ to represent $[b]D_0 a$ in the *second* line of this, because that would make $D_0$ meet $a$ without waiting for a $b$ to be supplied, and we would have gained nothing. Once we do resist, however, we do have
$$ D(S(KW)D) \to^* S(S(K D_0)(K (S(KW)D))I $$
which is a normal form that we can use as our $X$.

---

To get a slightly shorter solution for the particular case of $Xy=X$, we can note that when $W=K$, we don't actually need to carry the $y$ through all of the reductions because it's just going to be ignored by the $K$ in the end anyway, so it should be possible instead of $D$ to work with an $E$ with the reduction rule
$$ Eab \to aa $$
Indeed in that case, $X=EE$ works right out of the box in a single reduction!

We can then parallel the development of $D$ above:
$$ \begin{align} E &\equiv [a][b]D_0 a
\\&\equiv [a]S(K D_0)(K a)
\\&\equiv S(K(S(K D_0)))K\end{align}$$
and pre-reduce $EE$ to get
$$ \begin{align} EE &\equiv S(K(S(K D_0)))K E
\\&\to K(S(K D_0))E (K E)
\\&\to S(K D_0) (K E)
\\&\equiv \fbox{S(K(SII)) (K(S(K(S(K(SII))))K))} =: X \end{align}$$

We can see this reduce in practice:
$$ \begin{align} Xy &\equiv S(K D_0)(K E)y
\\&\to (K D_0 y)(K E y)
\\&\to^* D_0 E 
\\&\equiv SIIE
\\&\to^* EE
\\&\to^* X \qquad\text{as above} \end{align} $$

Comment: Beautiful answer. I wish I knew enough to produce such a creative answer! But unfortunately...I am not at that point presently! (Only a sad philosopher)

Anyway...look below for a simpler answer (not as creative as yours!)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well...I have been banned! It seems it depends on some answers I gave on my very first question on math.stackexchange. I didn't know that one could not say "thank you" as an answer, so I posted two or three "answers" of this kind, which were later automatically deleted.

But now, I cannot post any other answer! How can I get out of this misunderstanding?

Comment: @Antonio: I'm not exactly sure how the automatic post bans work, but you could try asking about it [on the meta site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-ban). My limited understanding is that the moderators cannot lift such a ban manually, but that they are usually supposed to decay after some time.

Answer (score 2):

In an extended version of Hindley's book I am reading (I'm dealing with "Introduction to combinatory logic", while the extended version is "Lambda calculus and combinators. An introduction") I have found the following remark.

Let us re-define abstraction in the following way:

- $[x]^*x$ identical to $I$
- $[x]^*M$ identical to $KM$ if $M$ is atomic different from $x$
- $[x]^*Ux$ identical to $U$ if $U$ is atomic different from $x$
- $[x]^*UV$ identical to $S([x]U)([x]V)$ if the previous cases cannot be applied.

Then, for every $X$, $[x]^*X$ is a weak normal form. By induction on the complexity of $X$, the atomic cases being trivial and the induction step being a simple application of the induction hypothesis.

With this remark, and by bearing in mind the theorem

$([x]^*X)Y > [Y/x]X$

(which therefore also holds for this re-defined abstraction, as easily provable - actually more simply then the previous abstraction) we can choose $[y]^*F([x, y]^*x)$, with $F$ fixed-point combinator. Such a term is normal according to the remark. By the theorem

$([y]^*F([x, y]^*x))y = F([x, y]^*x)$

and

$F([x, y]^*x) = ([x, y]^*x)(F([x, y]^*x)) = [y]^*F([x, y]^*x)$.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was trying to hint (tersely) at in my first answer. I am still unsure that it actually works for this purpose, however -- especially the very last equals sign. Since $[\cdot]^*$ works differently on a variable than on a complex term, it does not necessarily satisfy $([x]^* [y]^* x) M = [y]^* M$, which is what you need here.

Comment: Actually, we can compute directly: $[x,y]^* x$ presumably means $$[x]^* [y]^* x \equiv [x]^* (K x) \equiv S(KK)I,$$ and your last equals sign is then really $$ S(KK)I(F(S(KK)I)) \stackrel?= [y]^* F(S(KK)I) $$ But actually it reduces as $$ S(KK)I(F(S(KK)I)) \to\to K (F(S(KK)I)) $$ which is not obviously reduction-equivalent to $[y]^* F(S(KK)I)$.

Comment: (Technically, the problem is that the theorem you quote, $$([x]^* X)Y \to [Y/x]X,$$ only works really when $X$ does _not_ contain any $[\cdot]^*$ notation, because otherwise the substitution $[Y/x]X$ doesn't actually do what one would intuitively expect it to!)

Comment: You are right. In this case, just add to the definition of abstraction the clause

$[x]^*Mx$ identical to $M$ if $M$ is atomic different from $x$.

The theorem $([x]^*M)N = [N/x]M$ still works. Now, it should be ok, no?

Comment: x @Antonio: That would make $[x,y]^*x\equiv K$, so your $X$ is now $[y]^* FK\equiv S([y]^*F)(KK)$. But then $Xy=([y]^*F)yK=FK=K(FK)$ which is still different from $[y]^* FK$ -- as seen by the fact that $K(FK)$ has no normal form.

Comment: I see...what I cannot understand now is "why" it doesn't work. Having proved the theorem $([x]^*M)N = [N/x]M$, shouldn't it work then? Is this a kind of counterexample?

Anyway, the solution must be somehow tied with the fact that this new abstraction yields always weak normal forms.

Comment: Anyway, in my proof I used a different reduction. I do not re-write $[y]^*(F[x, y]^*x)$ and then apply reduction w.r.t. $y$, but I apply the theorem and then get $(F[x, y]^*x)$. Again, do not re-write $[x, y]^*x (F[x, y]^*x)$, but apply the theorem. This change the things? I mean, there could be a reduction of my combinator to normal form, and other reductions which do not bring to normal form. Perhaps, in avoiding to re-write $[y]^*(F[x, y]^*x)$, but rather applying the theorem, one finds an ending reduction. Whereas, if one reasons like you do, one finds a non ending reduction.

Comment: x @Antonio: You're still trying to apply that theorem to an $M$ that contains $[\cdot]^*$. That doesn't do what you imagine it will do -- if you examine your argument in detail you will see that it depends on assuming that $$ [Y/x]([x]^* \cdots x \cdots) \stackrel?\equiv [x]^* \cdots Y \cdots$$ when $Y$ is _not_ atomic. And this is _not_ true, because $[x]^*$ is a _meta-level_ operation that must be carried out _before_ the definition of substitution can be applied. And once you _have_ reduced $[x]^*\cdots x\cdots$ to pure combinators, there's nothing that "remembers" that ...

Comment: ... substituting a value in for $x$ was supposed to implicitly rewrite it as $[x]^*$ would have done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30961/discussion-between-antonio-piccolomini-daragona-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: x @Antonio: You can follow the chat link yourself too.

Comment: By looking more accurately at the section where the remark about the modified abstraction is introduced, I have seen that such a fact is used to proved that, if there is combinatore $X$ such that $X x_1, ..., x_n = Z$, then there is a combinator in normal form $X'$ such that $X' x_1, ..., x_n = Z$. Now, the exercise says "find a combinator $X$ such that $Xy = X$. Then, find a combinator $X'$ in normal form with the same property". Maybe, it simply means, find a combinator in normal form $X'$ such that $X'y = X$. In this case the solution would simply be $[y]^*X$.